# capability from different user namespace

Tags: posix, capability, linux-namespaces

I'm studying posix capabilities and namespace in linux and I wrote some lines of code inspired by these impressive [articles](https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/#series_index) to better comprehend how the capabilities are seen from different namespaces. Some piece of code are taken from the examples of the article, not my play...

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/capability.h>
#include "caputilities.h"


#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                        } while (0)
#define MAXLEN 255

/* Replace commas in mapping string arguments with newlines */
static void get_mapstr(char *map){
    if (map==NULL) return;
    size_t map_len = strlen(map);
    for (int j = 0; j < map_len; j++)
        if (map[j] == ',') map[j] = '\n';
}

static void save_map(char *map, char *map_file){
    int fd;
    fd = open(map_file, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t map_len = strlen(map);
    if (write(fd, map, map_len) != map_len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "write %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(fd);
}

/* Start function for cloned child */
static int childFunc(void *arg){
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    fprintf(stderr, "cloned child pid %ld\n", (long)pid);
    fprintf(stderr, "child process capabilities %s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_proc(), NULL));
    fprintf(stderr, "euid %ld, egid %ld\n", (long)geteuid(), (long)getegid());
    if (arg!=NULL){ //user ns enabled 
        char *uidmap = ((char **)arg)[0];
        char *gidmap = ((char **)arg)[1];
        if (uidmap!=NULL) fprintf(stderr, "setting uid map %s\n", uidmap);
        if (gidmap!=NULL) fprintf(stderr, "setting gid map %s\n", gidmap);
        char map_path[MAXLEN + 1];
        if (uidmap != NULL){
            snprintf(map_path, MAXLEN, "/proc/%ld/uid_map", (long)pid);
            save_map(uidmap, map_path);
        }
        if (gidmap != NULL){
            snprintf(map_path, MAXLEN, "/proc/%ld/gid_map", (long)pid);
            save_map(gidmap, map_path);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "child process capabilities %s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_proc(), NULL));
        fprintf(stderr, "euid %ld, egid %ld\n", (long)geteuid(), (long)getegid());
    }
    sleep(200);
    exit(0);
}

static void usage(char *pname){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -U -M mapstring -G mapstring\n", pname);
    fprintf(stderr, "       -U use user namespace\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "       -M uid mapping\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "       -G gid mapping\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "       mapstring is a comma separated list of mapping of the form:\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "       ID_inside-ns    ID-outside-ns   length [,ID_inside-ns    ID-outside-ns   length, ...]\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];    /* Space for child's stack */

/* Receive a UID and/or GID mapping as arguments
   Every mapping consists of a list of tuple (separated by new line) of the form:
       ID_inside-ns    ID-outside-ns   length
   Requiring the user to supply a string that contains newlines is
   of course inconvenient for command-line use. Thus, we permit the
   use of commas to delimit records in this string, and replace them
   with newlines before writing the string to the file. */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int flags = 0;
    char *gid_map = NULL, *uid_map = NULL;
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "UM:G:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt){
            case 'U': flags |= CLONE_NEWUSER;
            case 'M': uid_map = optarg; break;
            case 'G': gid_map = optarg; break;
            default: usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }
    if ((uid_map != NULL || gid_map != NULL) && !(flags & CLONE_NEWUSER)){
        fprintf(stderr,"what about give me the user namespace option? what's in your mind today?\n");
        usage(argv[0]);
    } 
    char* args[2];
    get_mapstr(uid_map); args[0] = uid_map;
    get_mapstr(gid_map); args[1] = gid_map; 
    pid_t child_pid = clone(childFunc, child_stack + STACK_SIZE, flags | SIGCHLD, (flags & CLONE_NEWUSER) ? &args : NULL);
    if (child_pid == -1) errExit("clone");
    sleep(1);
    fprintf(stderr, "child process pid capabilities from parent: %s\n", cap_to_text(cap_get_pid(child_pid), NULL));
    fprintf(stderr, "euid %ld, egid %ld\n", (long)geteuid(), (long)getegid());
    exit(0);
}
```

I proved that from the child in the new namespace it's only possible to map the effective user id in the external namespace of the parent process to any uid in the new namespace, root included, but if you try to map different external users from the child you get error. That's ok.

```
$ ./testcap3 -U -M"1000 39 1"
cloned child pid 7659
child process capabilities = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+ep
euid 65534, egid 65534
setting uid map 1000 39 1
write /proc/7659/uid_map: Operation not permitted
child process pid capabilities from parent: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+ep
euid 1000, egid 1000
$ ./testcap3 -U -M"0 1000 1"
cloned child pid 7665
child process capabilities = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+ep
euid 65534, egid 65534
setting uid map 0 1000 1
child process capabilities = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+ep
euid 0, egid 65534
child process pid capabilities from parent: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read+ep
euid 1000, egid 1000
```

I don't get why the capabilities of the child process are shown as all enabled when printed from the parent process.
I would've expected to see no priviliges in the external namespace, am I wrong?
Clearly the binary testcap3 is not privileged (neither setuid/setgid bit nor capabilities are set on the file and the effective user is not an admin)
How the capabilities are stored? How the data structures are related with namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I glanced over the capability code to find out the structures..

the user level libraries use the calls defined in `<sys/capability.h>` to fetch the capabilities set, specifically all libcap functions defined in [cappro.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap.git/tree/libcap/cap_proc.c) make use of the function capget to retrieve the data structures `cap_user_header_t` and `cap_user_data_t` defined in `<sys/capability.h>`
The syscall capget is defined at [capability.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/.../source/kernel/capability.c...), the purpose is updating the data structure pointed by `dataptr` (second argument of the syscall) with the capability set of the process `&header->pid` (passed by the first parameter), there is some boilerplate code to copy variables from kernelspace to userspace and vice versa..
The key call to [cap_get_target_pid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/kernel/capability.c#L118) passes by address the effective, permitted, inheritable capability sets.
The [cap_get_target_pid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/kernel/capability.c#L118) function, loads the task structure for the pid namespace of the pid received by argument thanks to the functions `task_pid_vnr` and [find_task_by_vpid](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/kernel/pid.c#L348).
In the initial check it uses the variable [current](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h#L13) which defines the current task in execution.
The function `security_capget` use the LSM framework which calls the capget hook [cap_capget](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/security/commoncap.c#L205) which reveals where the set are retrieved.. they are saved in the credential field of the task structure (there should be a different task structure for each pid namespace).
The hooks for the module cap are defined at the end of the file [commoncap.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/security/commoncap.c#L1345) 
Anyway again I don't figure out why it can't write on the mapping file different users if it has all capabilities set on in the parent pid namespace.
Still puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

I modified a little the test code to try to kill from the cloned child in the new namespace detecting the permission error as expected.
So I had the oppurtunity to dig into the kernel code to analyze how the authorization to kill are granted/denied.
The kernel compares the namespace of the process to kill with the current thread namespace, if they match it checks if the current thread has the flag effective for kill enabled.
Otherwise (not matching namespace) it checks if the current thread is an ancestor of the process who created the namespace of the process to kill, if so it allows to proceed the evaluation of other linux securiry modules if any.
Contrarily if the killer thread is a descendant of the target process and is not in the same namespace of the process the license to kill is denied.

The glibc defines a weak symbol for the kill userspace call defined in singnal.h, so I suppose the called code is defined at kernel level, these are the involved system calls:

[syscall to kill](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.6/source/kernel/signal.c#L3210)

[group_send_sig_info](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.6/source/kernel/signal.c#L1318)

[check_kill_permission](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.6/source/kernel/signal.c#L763)

[kill_ok_by_cred](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.6/source/kernel/signal.c#L747)

[hook to capable for lsm capability module](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20-rc5/source/security/commoncap.c#L71)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as the original post, and it seems I got an answer by asking a maintainer of `libcap`.

It looks like `cap_get_pid()` retrieves the capability within the user namespace of the target process with `pid`, which means that no matter who the caller is, it would not show a different result if the given `pid` is the same.

The confusion seems to be due to the lack of the document around the interaction between libcap and the user namespace. Since the user namespace is a relatively recent concept than the capabilities, I think there would need to be updates on the libcap API and its documentation around the interaction between the user namespaces and the capabilities.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215812 contains a request for a better documentation with the API.